# Relative path in http get or request in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, apache, nginx

I am trying to cache the contents and page dependencies using the Apache web server. The page structure and routing is defined below.

- The basic page is rendered from AEM server (Publish port 4503).
- The UI dependency like css, angular script is loading from Nginx (Nginx port 7000 with root folder "/ui").
- I have configured Nginx such that when I load the publish url with 7000 port, it gets static page content from 4503 publish port and overlays the ui dependency and displays complete page along with styles and angular routing.
- In Apache dispatcher, the port 8080 is configured to listen Nginx port 7000.
- So, when I hit the url "http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.html" in browser, the following contents are cached in Apache server.

  1. myproject -> index -> index.template.html, index.angular-app-controllers.js, index.angular-app-module.js.
  2. ui -> all the dependency files.

Now, the issue is tried to replicate the same thing by hitting the url using nodeJS. We did follow the below methods but none of them are successful.

Method 1:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.html', function(response) {
    console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers: ', response.headers);
    response.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

Method 2:

```
var request = require("request") 

var url = "http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.html"; 

request({ 
    url: url, 
    json: false 
}, function (error, response, body) { 

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) { 
        console.log(body) // Print the json response 
    } 
});
```

Method 3:

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var HttpProxyAgent = require('http-proxy-agent');

// HTTP/HTTPS proxy to connect to 
var proxy = 'http://myproxy:80/';
console.log('using proxy server %j', proxy);

// HTTP endpoint for the proxy to connect to 
var endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.html';
console.log('attempting to GET %j', endpoint);
var opts = url.parse(endpoint);

// create an instance of the `HttpProxyAgent` class with the proxy server information 
var agent = new HttpProxyAgent(proxy);
opts.agent = agent;

http.get(opts, function (res) {
  console.log('"response" event!', res.headers);
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

In all the above methods, we were able to get only the 'index.html' file. We were not able to get 'index.template.html' or any other angular files and the UI folder wasn't even created.

I tried debugging this issue, which ended in one relative path.

When the url is hit in browser, the path searched for require js is http://localhost:8080/ui/myproject/libs/requirejs/2.1.9/require.js.

But when the same url is hit using nodeJS require or request, the path being searched is [file:///D:/ui/myproject/libs/requirejs/2.1.9/require.js](http://file:///D:/ui/myproject/libs/requirejs/2.1.9/require.js).

So my question is, am I missing something or nodeJS is not able to append the hostname and port number dynamically.

I would be glad, if anyone can point my mistake or help me to overcome this issue in anyway. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well the difference between what you are doing and what the browser does is the browser makes the request to the server for index.html, it gets the response and then parses the page to find all other resources it needs to obtain to succesfully render your index page. This will fire multiple more requests, likely to your nginx server to get the ui folder ect. Can you not send seperate requests for each of the resources you need?

Comment: You need to use browser automation for this. See http://webdriver.io/

Comment: The resource for each page will be dynamic and it changes based on the content change. So I can't send separate request for each resource.